# Session not persist on Laravel 5.4

Tags: session, laravel-5.4

I'm having some problems with Laravel Sessions, now I'm working under Laravel 5.4, so, I'm using this code for set session:

```
$request->session()->put('usuario', 'somevalue');
```

But when I'm trying to get the session value from another function on same controller with this code:

```
$request->session()->get('usuario');
```

I'm getting NULL, I'm trying importing Session and using "web" middleware

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

But I still getting same error.

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::post('login','UsuarioController@login');
Route::get('usuariodatos','UsuarioController@getDatos');
});
```

Controller, function login:

```
$data=$request->json()->all();
    $user=Usuario::where('correo_electronico', $data['login_correo'])->first();

    if(!empty($user->id_usuario)) {
        if(Hash::check( $data['login_passwd'], $user->passwd) == true) {
            $request->session()->put('usuario', $user); 

            $ses = $request->session()->get('usuario');
          return json_encode(array("resultado" => $ses));

        } else {

        }
    } else {
    }
```

Controller function get session:

```
public function getDatos(Request $request)
{
  return json_encode(array("resultado"=>$request->session()->get('usuario')));
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Try to push `$request->session()->get('usuario');` after `$request->session()->put('usuario', 'somevalue');` and see if the session is set

Comment: Yes, I have just tried that, and It's ok I get the session value after set it, but when I go to another route I get NULL

Comment: can you show your routes , controllers ?

Comment: I just added it to my original post

Comment: Well I think `Hash::check( $data['login_passwd'], $user->passwd) == true` or `!empty($user->id_usuario` condition is false , that why your session didin't  set the value

Comment: No, the If logic is working well, the only problem is on the session, because you can see I set the session and then get the same session and I get the correct value for this, but when I go to another function and trying to get the session value I get NULL

Comment: the other function route is inside your `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web']`?

Comment: yes, both routes are on the same middleware

Comment: Can you put this line of code `$request->session()->put('usuario', 'test');` at the first line in the `login` function and see if there is a value in the `getDatos` function ?

Comment: doesn`t work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add :
    $request->session()->save();

after the put otherwise session will not persist.

It's strange that even in the official documentation this important detail doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `web` middleware. Since Laravel 5.3 it is applied by default to all routes.  If you apply it manually then the session logic is executed twice and it will break.

**A note on `session()->save()`:**

You don't need to call this if you are returning a Laravel response (ie `view()`, `response()` etc). Laravel will call this before returning the response. Again if you call this twice you might lose any flashed data from your session...