# Laravel 6 Session does not persist in web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-session

Both of the files I put together in web.php so that they share the same web middleware. But the session does not Store

I am create a SMS OTP system. In the API\SmsController@create function I run

```
$rand = rand(100000,999900);

session()->put('otp_test', $rand);
session()->keep(['otp_test']);
```

After the API request, I can see from Laravel Debugger in the SESSION tab have the session variable.

However, when I refresh the page, the SESSION variable is not there . It only leave

```
_token                  Zv3IpiLwwIXTUMc4tMW1J9eJA5lJCliGtdwEvx0e
_previous               array:1 [ "url" => "http://sms.test/register" ]
_flash                  array:2 [ "old" => [] "new" => [] ]
url                     array:1 [ "intended" => "http://sms.test" ]
PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA
```

[image]
Also when I do the Form Post, `session('otp_test')` also NULL.

After I refresh the page. There is `opt_test` session there.
[image]

I tried file, database in session.php both also not persist when I refresh or go to next page.
It seem like flash it after all.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. API requests doesn't use sessions.

Comment: After remove the `session()->keep(['otp_test']);` then it work.. I thought `->keep()` function is to keep it. Anyone have idea why not woring after added the `keep()`

Comment: @EliasSoares I had move both API\ into the web.php, both are sharing same middlesware.

Comment: Your api is using cookie based authentication so?

Comment: my didn't api.php for this case. I move all the route into `web.php`, from the `artisan route:list` I had checked both middleware is `web`

Comment: Previously I do separate them between `web.php` and `api.php` but I notice the API middleware didn't start session. So I move everything into web.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keep` method is for **flashed** session data. Flashed session variables will end up getting removed. You just turned your regular session variable (that would exist until you remove it, the session is flushed or dies) into a flashed variable that will get removed automatically by calling `keep` like that.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Sessions - Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#flash-data)

Comment: can you explain more `flashed` session, how does it work where to define? And I even read in stackoverflow said using `save()`. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290480/session-not-persist-on-laravel-5-4/48291574`

Comment: @Shiro i added a link for the laravel docs for flash data as a start ... your session is persisting, you just ended up having a flashed variable which gets removed automatically because of calling `keep`

Comment: it is only this particular session variable that is not persisting? if you set other ones and do not call `keep` they are still in your session after a new request?

Comment: Yes, only this particular session. Ya I think it is due to I am using the `keep` method. After removed then OK. First mistake, I use wrong middleware, then online search solution then use wrong method. Thanks for the help!